# How do I move the menu dropdown content to so they are in line with the left edge of the button?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to fix my menu code so that when I hover over the button, the dropdown menu will be in line with the left edge of the button. Right now it is spaced a bit to the right like a list.

HTML:

```
<center>
    <div class="menubar">
      <button class="button">Forms
      <div class="menubar-content">
        <a href="#">Department Update Form</a>
        <a href="#">Project Start Month Form</a>
        <a href="#">Add New Employee Form</a>
      </div>
      </button>
      <button class="button">Reports
      <div class="menubar-content">
        <a href="#">Human Resource's Employees Report</a>
      </div>
      </button>
      <button class="button">Reports
      <div class="menubar-content">
        <a href="#">Human Resource's Employees Report</a>
        <a href="#">2012 04 Product Plan Project Report</a>
        <a href="#">Department Data Report</a>
        <a href="#">Employee Business Info Report</a>
        <a href="#"></a>
      </div>
      </button>
    </div> 
</center>
```

CSS:

```
.button {
background-color: blue;
color: white;
padding: 16px;
font-size: 16px;
border: none;
cursor: pointer;
margin:5px;
}

.menubar {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.menubar-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 200px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    margin: 16px;
}

.menubar-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.menubar-content a:hover {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.button:hover .menubar-content {
    display: block;

}

.menubar:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's responding to the padding you have on the button because it's within the `<button>` tag. So you simply counter it with a negative margin on the div.

```
.menubar-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 200px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    margin: 16px;
    margin-left: -16px; //add this line
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I would have never though of that.

Comment: No prob. If worked, would you mind accepting my answer as correct to help people who find this later?

Comment: Sure! You missed your colon after margin-left though. No worries.

Comment: Good catch. Fixed.